# ASPOSE Converting PDF to SVG via streams produces invalid results

Tags: c#, .net, aspose, .net-standard-2.0

I'm trying to convert a pdf document into svg pages. My first attempt was to load the pdf document and save it as a stream and then load that supposedly converted svg stream as a SVGDocument, this however produces a garbage object.

```
pageDocument.Save(ms, SaveFormat.Svg);
pageDocument.Save("temp.svg", SaveFormat.Svg);

// Object is invalid
var svgDocument1 = new SVGDocument(ms, ".");

// Create a FileStream object
using (var stream = new FileStream("temp.svg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
   // Valid object
   var svgDocument2 = new SVGDocument(stream, ".");
}
```

By slightly modifying the code to save the pdf page as a svg image and then loading that as a file stream works perfectly, so I am not sure what is going on here.

Needles to say, I want to try and avoid creating unnecessary files just for the sake of conversion.

Answer (score 0):

As shared in the [forum thread](https://forum.aspose.com/t/not-able-to-convert-from-pdf-to-svg-via-stream/223843/10?u=asad.ali) over the official forum, seeking the memory stream back to the beginning will resolve the issue. Please add the following line of code before loading the SVGDocument from MemoryStream:

```
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

We are also going to add descriptions to the API that document is processed from the current position in the stream as working with positions in streams is a regular practice described in Microsoft documentation.